# How to build openldap with custom libopenssl

Tags: c, linux, openssl, openldap, configure

I need to build libldap under linux (and windows, but that's a different story).

When I do

```
./configure --prefix="$OPENLDAP_BUILD_PATH" --disable-slapd
make
make install
make clean
```

I get with `ldd` that libldap is linked with system libraries libssl.so and libcrypto.so. And what I need is to link it with my custom builds of this libraries.

I also tried this:

```
OPENLDAP2_BUILD_PATH="$BUILD_PATH/openldap2"
mkdir "$OPENLDAP2_BUILD_PATH"

OPENSSL_DEPENDENCY_PATH="$BUILD_PATH/openssl"

LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$OPENSSL_DEPENDENCY_PATH/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
CPPFLAGS="-l$OPENSSL_DEPENDENCY_PATH/include/openssl"
LDFLAGS="-L$OPENSSL_DEPENDENCY_PATH/lib"

./configure --prefix="$OPENLDAP2_BUILD_PATH" --disable-slapd
make
make install
make clean
```

With no success either.

ldd libldap.so shows this:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc91923000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /home/me/Work-U14/proj/shared/BUILD/openldap2/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007ff0ef638000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007ff0ef3f8000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007ff0ef198000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007ff0eedbc000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff0ee9f4000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff0ee7ef000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056386adf5000)
```

Comment: What does `ldd -p` show once the libraries are installed? You should also show a typical compile command; and your link command. Don't trust SONAME's. They seem mostly broken on Linux. Use SONAME's combined with RPATH's to ensure the expected library is linked at runtime. Finally, variables like `CPPFLAGS`, `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` are *not* colon delimited like a `PATH`. They should look exactly like they do on the command line with spaces.

Comment: ldd doesn't recognize option -p. added ldd output to post.

Compilation  looks like this in makefile:

LTCOMPILE_LIB = $(LIBTOOL) $(LTONLY_LIB) --mode=compile \
 $(CC) $(LT_CFLAGS) $(LT_CPPFLAGS) $(LIB_DEFS) -c

Can't dig in much better for now.

Comment: Add a RPATH for OpenSSL and OpenLDAP. For OpenSSL, see [Compilation and Installation | Using RPATHs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Using_RPATHs) on the OpenSSL wiki. For OpenLDAP, add it to `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: libraries like openssl and openldap will be put locally in one dir after build. Is there a real necessity in rpaths in that case? How can I rpath to the distro folder?

Comment: IMO, there'll be no use of RPATH since libs are to be a part of distro.

Comment: For me, RPATHs are not one of those religious debates. I use them to solve problems like detailed at [OpenSSL and RPATH's (was: Cannot find SSL_CTX_get0_param in libssl library)](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/OpenSSL-and-RPATH-s-was-Cannot-find-SSL-CTX-get0-param-in-libssl-library-td70913.html). I think SONAMEs would work if they included a path, like Apple's `install_name`. But they don't, and the linker get confused as hell (as shown in that thread).

Comment: I've managed to build libldap statically but with all this autoconf stuff it makes me uncomfortable. So I'll write premake script for openldap.

Comment: I've built it, passing exported variable with full path to my open ssl. It's not optimal, for it's not portable, but that's good enough for now, I think. I don't think that's the "ANSWER", but quite a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good solution, but a well-enough workaround for me.

1. I've written build.sh as follows:

   #!/bin/sh

   if [ -z "$BUILD_PATH" ]
   then
       echo "Variable BUILD_PATH isn't specified!"
       exit
   fi

   OPENLDAP2_BUILD_PATH="$BUILD_PATH/openldap2"

   export MY_OPENSSL_ROOT="$BUILD_PATH/openssl"

   ./configure --prefix=$OPENLDAP2_BUILD_PATH --disable-slapd >/home/sherst/Desktop/configure_log.openldap2 2>&1
   make >/home/sherst/Desktop/make_log.openldap2 2>&1
   make install >/home/sherst/Desktop/make_install_log.openldap2 2>&1
2. I've patched configure file as such:

**LINE 15485** 
`LIBS="-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/ -L. -lssl -lcrypto $LIBS"`

**LINE 15582**
`TLS_LIBS="-Wl,-rpath=$MY_OPENSSL_ROOT/lib -L$MY_OPENSSL_ROOT/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lRSAglue -lrsaref"`

**LINE 15584** 
`TLS_LIBS="-Wl,-rpath=$MY_OPENSSL_ROOT/lib -L$MY_OPENSSL_ROOT/lib -lssl -lcrypto"`

3. In such way (I'm quite sure that it's very crude and overabundant) I've achieved that ldd shows links to my openssl libs. TO hard code them is a bad idea, but when, in distro, there will be no such paths, I expect ld to find them in local dir, where we plan to put them.
4. openldap faq [says](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/185.html) this should be achieved ain such way:

   env CPPFLAGS=-I/path/to/openssl/include \
         LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/openssl/lib-dir \
         configure --with-tls ...

But that didn't work for me (perhaps, I did it wrong).

Answer (score 2):

Found that below could work:
`export LDFLAGS="-L/your/dir/to/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/your/dir/to/openssl/include"
./configure ...`
 could work, the include path is:
`-I/your/dir/to/openssl/include` **NOT** 
`-I/your/dir/to/openssl/include/openssl` 
which the .h head files are all in the sub `openssl` dir under `include`,
the key point is get rid of the `openssl` dir under `include` dir, which by default for other packages we have to add this sub-directory under `include`, e.g. for `apr`, you have to make it as: `-I/your/dir/to/apr/include/apr-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I found info how to add rpath here:

https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/install.html

Simply pass it to configure script:

```
/configure --enable-wrappers \
                CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" \
                LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib"
```